# How `agenda.js` calculates timezone for `every()` operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, agenda

I am using `agenda.js` in my Node project, backed with a MongoDB database, to handle batch processes we need to run. This is working well. I do have a question about timezones, however. When I use the `every()` operation, it seems like it accepts the job name, and the schedule. So I have been seeding jobs to the database like so:

```
  for (let job of dbJobs) {
    await agenda.every(schedule, job.name);
  }
```

Note that for the above, `schedule` is in cron format -- `00 05 * * 1-5`.

This works. However, from what I can tell, `every()` doesn't accept an argument for `repeatTimezone`. So what does it do to calculate the timezone in those cases?

To clarify, when I look at the document in the database after the job has been added using `every()`, the `repeatTimezone` property exists, but its value is set to `null`.

Other `agenda` operations, like `repeatEvery()`, *do* accept an argument for timezone, like so:

```
job.repeatEvery('0 6 * * *', {
  timezone: 'America/New_York'
});
```

Since I'm using `every()`, I have been managing this by first seeding the database using `every()`, and then running a Mongo `updateMany()` to add the timzeone explicitly to all jobs:

```
async function addTimezoneToJobs() {
  try {
    const db = await client.db(dbName);
    await db.collection('batch_processes').updateMany({}, {
      $set: {
        repeatTimezone: 'America/New_York'
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

But strangely enough, `agenda` seems to calculate the same time even when I don't explicitly add the `repeatTimezone` property value to the jobs as when I do.

What's happening here that I'm not understanding? How is the runtime calculated with `every()`, and is there a way to pass in timezone?

FYI: I am not in the same timezone as that which needs to be set in the db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Question seems to be 2 part, I'm not exactly sure I'll be able to explain it very well but let me try

So, your first question

> However, from what I can tell, `every()` doesn't accept an argument for Timezone

Well Technically you can add `Timezone` option to `every()` as well because what this method does is it calls `job.repeatEvery` internally and as you already know you can add `timezone` to that. To Support my answer, I found 2 evidence

1. From [Documentation](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#everyinterval-name-data-options) as `every` accepts 4 parameters

> every(interval, name, [data], [options])

> `options` is an optional argument that will be passed to `job.repeatEvery`. In order to use this argument, data must also be specified.

So you can **technically** pass `timezone` if you pass `data` as well

2. From [SourceCode](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/blob/7e78b71b79ae6c6d874e9180954b8b84248e9848/lib/agenda/every.ts#L42), here you can see they use `job.repeatEvery(interval, options)` internally.

Now, To your Second Question

> what does it do to calculate the timezone in those cases?

Well They have a very unique yet required module named [ComputeNextRunAt()](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/blob/7e78b71b79ae6c6d874e9180954b8b84248e9848/lib/job/compute-next-run-at.ts#L16).

So I went through their Source Code and figured Out that this is to Compute when will be the next run for your job based on startingTime and Interval.

Your Code works because you have once (Initially) mentioned in your job to follow `America/New_York` timezone, so every next job interval is calculated based on that, that's the reason you don't need to specify it again.

So, If initially you haven't had specified the timezone attribute, you would have gotten your `local Timezone` but now you did so, it calculates the next interval based on that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the very thorough answer, @Shivram!

Comment: No worries! 

PS- It's `Shivam` not `Shivram`